# My app keep closing in the emulator after migrate to androidx. Does anyone have solution for this?

Tags: android

I just migrated to androidx. For some reason, my app keeps crashing whenever I use it in the emulator. I need help

I have been searching on the Internet for hours but have not seen any  solution for that. I also examine my logcat but I do not get the error

```
2019-10-16 18:33:11.287 7763-7763/com.example.recyclerview E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.recyclerview, PID: 7763
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.recyclerview/com.example.recyclerview.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class androidx.core.widget.DrawerLayout
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class androidx.core.widget.DrawerLayout
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class androidx.core.widget.DrawerLayout
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.core.widget.DrawerLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.recyclerview-gS5TXhudi0GJX8tyIujcvA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.recyclerview-gS5TXhudi0GJX8tyIujcvA==/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at com.example.recyclerview.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the activity java and xml file with drawer layout replace `androidx.core.widget.DrawerLayou` with `androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout`. If you can't see it directly, use find option and search the string directly.

Comment: But where do I go to change it? What is the location?

Comment: @Kevin in activity where you have used the drawer layout. You know which activity has drawer layout, right?

Comment: The problem is I don't even use the androidx.core.widget.DrawerLayout. I use the androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout in my MainActivity

Comment: The following classes could not be found:
- android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)
- android.support.design.widget.NavigationView (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)
- android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)
- android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)
- androidx.core.widget.DrawerLayout (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)

Comment: because the xml is still using controls from old support library which you need to go in each xml file by clicking edit XML and replace them with appropriate androidx control

Comment: Oh i made it. Thanks a lot my friend. You're awesome!

Answer (score 1):

try to change `androidx.core.widget.DrawerLayout` with `androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout`

Comment: But where do I go to change it?

Answer (score 1):

Your error message says your layout used in `com.example.recyclerview.MainActivity.onCreate` contains the class `androidx.core.widget.DrawerLayout`, but the package name for `DrawerLayout` is [`androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/drawerlayout/widget/DrawerLayout). Correct your layout to use the right class name.